# Share in Google+

Tags: android, google-plus

I need share link in Google+ from Android app. In documentation I saw this code:

```
Button shareButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share_button);
shareButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
       // Launch the Google+ share dialog with attribution.
        Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(ExampleActivity.this)
           .setType("text/plain")
           .setText("Welcome to the Google+ platform. https://developers.google.com/+")
           .getIntent()
           .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");

        startActivity(shareIntent);
    } 
});
```

But it will work if on my phone is official client Google+. Can I share link in Google+ without to use official client.

Comment: Yes, but then you must have google+ api.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Google+_API

Answer (score 0):

Google+ API doesn't support share. Link: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/plus/v1/

Answer (score 0):

The Share Intent, shown in the code you've provided. uses the native Google+ application to share content to Google+. This is the only way to share content to Google+ on Android.