# Google Plus Integration in android app

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-api, google-plus

I am using Google+ in my app. And I can share content using following code

```
Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(ViewGooglePlus.this)
                    .setText("Android Testing for Google+")
                    .setType("text/plain")
                    .setContentUrl(
                            Uri.parse("http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.in/"))
                    .getIntent()
                    .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
            startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
```

but it works only when official Google+ client is installed on device.

I want to share content whether official Google+ client is installed in device or not.

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882775/share-in-google) that it is possible using [this](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/plus/v1/java/latest/) library but don't know how to use it ?

Is it possible? Anybody have an idea? If yes, how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You cant share to Google+ if the application is not installed in the device. You can use Google App Engine and `Google+ APIs` to share the content.

```
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Google+_API
```

One such example can be found [here on Git](https://github.com/imellon/Google-Plus-Android-Sample).

```
https://github.com/imellon/Google-Plus-Android-Sample
```

Comment: using google app engine and api is it possible ? or still Google+ must be installed on device ?

Comment: Google+ isnt required in this case but you will need to add Google+ Apis in your app. You can check the github page I shared.

Comment: I found client_id in API Console but where can I find client_secret ?

Comment: The example on github is old and you can check https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/oauth-and-tasks-on-android to authenticate and get the access token.

Comment: Why I posted that github example is to let you know how you can use Google APIs.

Comment: In sample shows how to login and fecthing User Info. But how to upload media File. On google+.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go for **OAuth Authentication** of Google Plus. This will provide explicit Authentication then Intent based.

In this mechanism, you are creating one `WebView` and open link of Google login page. When user is login successful, google return an Token, which you can use in your application to work with its different application like Maps, Location, Google+ etc.

Here is link which have [demo application](https://github.com/ddewaele/AndroidOauth2GoogleApiJavaClient).

You need to register yourself with Google Console and put two important information clientId and clientSecrets.

```
GOOGLE_PLUS("client id","client secret","https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",BearerToken.authorizationHeaderAccessMethod(),PlusScopes.PLUS_ME,"http://localhost","plus","https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/activities/public")
```